# Routing/Subnetting issues

Tags: routes, subnet

I am an absolute newb when it comes to networking.

I have one router (I think they're technically a router/switch combo) who connects directly to the internet, and both my laptop and another router (again might be a combo) connect to it wireless. From that second router, there's an ethernet cable to a desktop computer.

The first router has internal ip address 192.168.0.1
My laptop has internal ip address 192.168.0.244
The second router has external ip address 192.168.0.118
The second router has internal ip address 192.169.0.1
The desktop computer has internal ip address 192.169.0.2

My firewall is disabled on the desktop computer, so it's not blocking anything.

The ping reports :

From my desktop, I can ping to every device, including the laptop and the main router that connects to the internet. From my laptop however, I can only ping to the main router. I should normally also be able to ping to 192.168.0.118 which should bring me to the second router, but that's not working... Any thoughts what may cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the settings on my intermediate router did not allow for pinging. Just changing the setting did the trick.